# Why the ArrayList comes out to be empty in the below code

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, collections

The questions wants us to return all the subsets of an array in a list.But in the below code why The list lt remains empty after the code is executed?
According to me this list lt should have stored all the subsets....

```
class Solution {
    public void sub(int idx,int[] nums,List<Integer> arr,ArrayList<List<Integer>> lt){
        if(idx>=nums.length){
            lt.add(arr);
            // System.out.println(arr.toString());
            return;
        }
        arr.add(nums[idx]);
        sub(idx+1,nums,arr,lt);
        arr.remove(arr.size()-1);
        sub(idx+1,nums,arr,lt);
    }

    public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
        List<Integer> arr=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<List<Integer>> lt=new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        sub(0,nums,arr,lt);
        return lt;
    }
}
```

Comment: It might depend on how they are called, which you left out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code is that it's modifying the same arr list instance throughout the recursion. When it adds the list arr to the list lt, it's actually adding a reference to the same list instance. As a result, when the code modifies arr, it's also modifying the lists stored in lt.

```
class Solution {
    public void sub(int idx,int[] nums,List<Integer> arr,ArrayList<List<Integer>> lt){
        if(idx>=nums.length){
            lt.add(new ArrayList<>(arr));
            // System.out.println(arr.toString());
            return;
        }
        arr.add(nums[idx]);
        sub(idx+1,nums,arr,lt);
        arr.remove(arr.size()-1);
        sub(idx+1,nums,arr,lt);
    }

    public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
        List<Integer> arr=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<List<Integer>> lt=new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        sub(0,nums,arr,lt);
        return lt;
    }
}
```

Comment: But Sir than why I am getting all the subsets when I print the list arr individually (I am refering to the commented line)?

Answer (score 1):

> The list lt remains empty after the code is executed?

The `List` of `List`s doesn't.  However, every time you add a `List` to that collection, it is *the same* `List` object.  You ultimately remove every element you ever add to that `List`, so you end up with a `List` of many references to the same empty `List`.

Instead of adding an element to the one `List` and later removing it, make a new *copy* of the `List` each time you to add an element, and add the element (only) to the copy.  Never remove any elements.  This will ultimately result in 2<sup>*n*</sup> distinct `List` objects for an array of length *n*, which is indeed the number to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have only one `arr` reference and you keep adding same to the `lt`. at the end it is blank array and reflecting to all.

You can make a copy of `arr`(Clone it) and then add `it`

```
lt.add((ArrayList)((ArrayList)arr).clone());
```

Comment: But Sir than why I am getting all the subsets when I print the list arr individually (I am refering to the commented line)?